# visual Studio 2010 regular expressions for 'Find In Files'

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, findinfiles

I have look at the many stackoverflow posts concerning VS regular expressions and read the Microsoft page concerning regular expressions but still cannot determine where I am going wrong.

[Microsoft VS regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx/)

I want to find all lines which include the word, attribute, but which are not comment lines (do not contain the // symbol).

I have tried using the regular expression

```
~(^ *//).*attribute.*

meaning:
~(^ *//)   --> exclude lines which begin with '//' preceded by zero or more spaces
.*         --> match any character zero or more times
attributes --> match the word attributes
.*         --> match any character that comes after the word attribute
```

I have tried several other regular expressions with about the same amount of failure.  I am wondering if anyone can spot something obvious that I am not doing.

I also gave the below a try:

```
~( *//).*attribute.*  (thinking maybe the carat was being taken as a literal instead of special)

~(//).*attribute.* (thinking maybe the * was being taken as a literal instead of special)

~(//)attribute (imminent failure but will try anything)

\s*~(//).*attributes.*
```

I saw quite a few posts suggesting to use the find command in batch.  This can be done, but I would prefer to have the ability to double click on the findings so that the file will be opened and already scrolled to the correct location.

[image]

Comment: What about `^ *~(//).*<attribute>`? Hmm, your `~( *//).*attribute.*` should actually work almost as well...

Comment: Hi Yirkha, I tried the regular expression but it did not exclude the forward slashes.  thanks though for the suggestion

Comment: Could it be that you have tabs somewhere instead of spaces? So `^~(:b*//).*<attributes>`? (Too bad I don't have VS2010 installed anymore.)

Comment: the regex `^~(:b*//).*<attributes>` actually worked perfectly.  Thanks Yirkha.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one.

```
^(?=.*attribute.*\n)(?!.*//).*
```